# Why is there no inverse function in this case?

Tags: functions

There is no inverse function for $R(q) = 40q - 4q^2$ for $0≤q≤10$
But when $0≤q≤5$ there is inverse function. It's something about the function being one-to-one but I don't know why it isn't one-to-one.

Comment: Hint: $R(10-q)=R(q)$.

Comment: When $q=0$, $R(q)=0$.  Similarly, when $q=10$, $R(q)=0$.  Therefore, there is no inverse function in $[0,10]$ because knowing that the output is $0$ is not enough to figure out what the input was.  This function is not one-to-one on $[0,10]$ because there are two inputs with the same output.

Comment: Maybe draw a graph?

Answer (score 0):

$R'(q)=40-8q$ and thus, if $q\in[0,5[$, then $R'(q)>0$ and thus, $R$ is one to one on $[0,5]$. Therefore, there is an inverse $R^{-1}:R([0,5])\to[0,5]$. If $q\in[0,10]$, it's easy to see that for example $R(4)=R(6)$ therefore it's not injective and thus not bijective.

Comment: Wha Surb says, is that a a continuous strictly monotonic function can be shown to be ono-to-one with its image.  $R$ is obviously continuous and on $[0,5]$ it is strictly monotonic because $R'>0$.

Answer (score 0):

A function $f(x)$ must be one-to-one to have an inverse. This means that you can't have two values, $x_1$ and $x_2$ that are different from each other but map to the same number (that is, $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$).

For your function $R$, note that on the interval $0 \le q \le 10$, you can find two such numbers. For example, $R(0) = R(10) = 0$. So $R$ is not one-to-one on that interval and therefore has no inverse.

Can you finish the problem? How do you know that $R$ is one-to-one when $0 \le q \le 5$?